How to download NetIQ Access Manager?
I wanted to ask if someone could explain to me how to download NetIQ Access Manager.
I have created an account on MicroFocus and OpenText. I also tried asking on the MicroFocus community, but so far without any results. I can't find any guides online about this.
I'm not sure if my account needs to be enabled or what specifically to be able to download this application.
Thank you in advance.

You need to go to sld.microfocus.com and login with an account that is entitled to download that product.
See the tutorial video on Youtube:
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ILMIcWnwO-Q&list=PL8yfmcqTN8GE9XCGVgxMQDFFZy9_-R-e3&index=5&pp=iAQB
Also from the SLD site you can contact support if you have trouble finding the correct download.
